# How to return a string in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Hi i would ask you a question.
i have this hashmap and string and uuid:

```
private HashMap<UUID, String> uuidCodeMap;
private String randomcode;
private UUID uuid;
```

and the string that i put in is random:

```
randomcode = new Random().nextInt(800000)+200000+"H";
map.put(entity.getUniqueId(), randomcode);
```

now in another class i would get the code that the player have insert in the hashmap,
how can i do?
In the another class i've also tryed (i have getter and setter randomcode) and used

```
String code = df.getUuidCodeMap().get(df.getUuid());
```

but still don't give me the message written by the entity in the HashMap

a small example:

```
private String command = "verify"; 
private HashMap<UUID, String> uuidCodeMap; 
private List<UUID> verified; 
private Main main; 
private UUID uuid; 
private String randomcode;
```

in the part of the code:

```
uuid = p.getUniqueId();
randomcode = new Random().nextInt(800000)+200000+"H";  
uuidCodeMap.put(uuid, randomcode);
```

another class:

```
if (df.getUuidCodeMap().containsKey(df.getUuid())) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something
            return;
        }
```

but return a different randomcode

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Can you add the code to your question? (there is an "edit" link just below your question)

Comment: I think you might want to brush up your knowledge on how a Map (or Hash Map) works and what it's supposed to do. You map a key to a value. Using the key, you can find the value. In your example, the first map would have a String key and a UUID value. But in your last example you have a map from UUID to String? What do you want to achieve? The most basic methods of a Map are `put` and `get` to put a key-value pair into the map or get one out. You can use the `containsKey` to check whether a key exists in the map. There is also a `containsValue` method, but key->value should be more efficient

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: sorry to try again here, the docs have already read them to me and I was simply wrong to copy the class
i will modify now

Comment: I don't understand what this question is about. You have two different maps, one called "map" and another called "uuidCodeMap", and you put random numbers in them? And then you try to look something up in both of them? Can you edit the question to include an example  that we can actually run and see what it does ?

Comment: no I copied a different class and that's the wrong part of the class, it says what I want to do in the message

Comment: Does `df.getUuidCodeMap()` return the same `uuidCodeMap` you populated in an earlier snippet? Do `p.getUniqueId()` and `df.getUuid()` return the same value?

Comment: df.getUuidCodeMap() return the same, df.getUuid() is a getter of uuid (that in my class = p.getUniqueId())